# Intent that checks onItemSelected and radio checked * 

Tags: java, android

Newbie here again, thanks for al the help on my other questions.
I have everything working, But my On click button I need to apply which radio id or array the spinner group pulled the array from and soi can forward to the correct page.
I am mainly having a problem with the btn1 How to properly structure the if statements after the &
Any guidance as always is greatly appreciated.

Found the solution!!! 
Posted at bottom!!
 String

```
   <string name="prov_picker">Select a Province</string>
    <string-array name="prov_array">
        <item>-- Select Province --</item>
        <item>British Columbia</item>
        <item>Alberta</item>
        <item>Saskatchewan</item>
        <item>Manitoba</item>
        <item>Ontario</item>
        <item>Quebec</item>
        <item>New Brunswick</item>
        <item>Nova Scotia</item>
        <item>Newfoundland</item>
    </string-array>
     <string-array name="prov1_array">
        <item>-- Select Province --</item>
        <item>British Columbia</item>
        <item>Alberta</item>
        <item>Saskatchewan</item>
        <item>Manitoba</item>
        <item>Ontario</item>
        <item>Quebec</item>
        <item>New Brunswick</item>
        <item>Nova Scotia</item>
        <item>Newfoundland</item>
    </string-array>
 <string name="radio1">Provincial</string>    
 <string name="radio2">Federal</string> 

Java
mport android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View;

public class CanProvselect extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private RadioGroup RadioProvs;
    private Button btn1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.canprovselect);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        RadioProvs = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgProvs);
        RadioProvs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.radio_1 :
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.prov_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);     
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            //spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(
            //      ));
            break;
        case R.id.radio_2 :
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.prov1_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);     
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            //spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(
            //      ));
            break;

        }

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Spinner sp =    (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                String spinnerString = null;
                spinnerString = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (spinnerString.equalsIgnoreCase("British Columbia") && R.id.equals("radio_1")){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent (v.getContext(), ProvBC.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                } else 
                    if (spinnerString.equalsIgnoreCase("British Columbia") && R.id.equals("radio_2")){
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent (v.getContext(), FederalProvBC.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    } 

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Solution**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Spinner sp =    (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            String spinnerString = null;
            spinnerString = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (spinnerString.equalsIgnoreCase("British Columbia") && (checkedId == R.id.radio_1)){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent (v.getContext(), ProvBC.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            } else 
                if (spinnerString.equalsIgnoreCase("British Columbia") && (checkedId == R.id.radio_2)){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent (v.getContext(), FederalProvBC.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                } 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All I actuall found the solution to my problem.. Thought I would post the answer in case anyone might need it.
Radio buttons will select diffrent arrays and the submit button will redirect to pages